# Solving a Kummer equation with variables

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, equation

I am trying to solve a Kummer equation with an unknown inside it, which has to be solved numerically. x1 and x2 needs to be the same value.

I have done this with a for loop for all values of x1 and then solving for x2 and going forward if these values are the same, but this takes to much time and makes the code very slow. Thus I am trying to solve it as an equation with nsolve but gets the typeerror: "TypeError: cannot create mpf from 1.25/x1"

Under is the code which contains the problem, I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, nsolve, Symbol
import cmath
from mpmath import *
r=0.07
alpha=0.5
t=0.15
theta=1
sigma=0.4
C=1
k=0.1

a = (1/2)*(sigma**2)
b = -(1/2)*(sigma**2)-k
c = -r

d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

gamma_2 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
gamma_1 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

V_1 = (1-t)/(r+k)
V_2 = ((1-t)*k*theta)/(r*(r+k))

x1 = Symbol('x1')
x2 = Symbol('x2')
f1 = x1-x2
f2 = hyp1f1((1-gamma_2, 3-2*gamma_2 + (2*k/sigma**2),(2*k*theta)/((sigma**2)*x1))/(hyp1f1(-gamma_2,2-2*gamma_2 + (2*k/sigma**2),(2*k*theta)/((sigma**2)*x1))) + (x2*gamma_2-((V_1*(x2**2))/(V_1*x2+V_2-(1-t)*(C/r))))/((gamma_2*k*theta)/((1-gamma_2)*(sigma**2)+k)))
print(nsolve((f1, f2), (x1, x2), (-1, 1))) 1)))
```

Comment: The code as shown gives a different error and also has many unnecessary imports. Please simplify it and ensure that you post the full code (e.g. where is k defined?).

Comment: Hello Oscar! 

Ty for the comments. Have changed a bit now and included the forgotten value k.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are passing non-numeric values to the mpmath function. The expression you gave in the question also has parentheses location issues. I don't think there is any way to use nsolve if you are using an mpmath function that needs numerical arguments but you include as one of its arguments the variable for which you are trying to solve. Using bisection with a lambda function might be more productive:

```
z = lambda x1: S(hyp1f1(1-gamma_2, 3-2*gamma_2 + (2*k/sigma**2),(2*k*theta)/((sigma**2)*x1))/hyp1f1(-gamma_2,2-2*gamma_2 + (2*k/sigma**2),(2*k*theta)/((sigma**2)*x1)) + (x1*gamma_2-((V_1*(x1**2))/(V_1*x1+V_2-(1-t)*(C/r))))/((gamma_2*k*theta)/((1-gamma_2)*(sigma**2)+k)))
```

In this expression I have replaced `x2` with `x1` (since they must be equal). Now you can calculate `z(.1) -> 8.09413738178983`. Once you find values of `x1` that bound a root, you can use bisection to refine the bounds. There is a discontinuity at 0 to watch out for, otherwise it has a nice crossing for `x1 > 0` that can be found with a simple bisection routine.

```
def bisect(f,a,b,nstep=100):
 fa=f(a)
 fb=f(b)
 assert fa*fb <= 0
 for i in range(nstep):
  m=(a+b)/2
  fm=f(m)
  if sign(fm)==sign(fa):
   a=m;fa=fm
  else:
   b=m;fb=fm
 return m
```

This gives a solution near 0.4:

```
>>> bisect(z,.4,.5)
0.4388673830531
```

Comment: Hello and ty @smichr

I have looked at the parentheses issue and changed the formula to: 

```
(((hyp1f1(1-gamma_2, 3-2*gamma_2 + (2*k/sigma**2),(2*k*theta)/((sigma**2)*x1)))/(hyp1f1(-gamma_2,2-2*gamma_2 + (2*k/sigma**2),(2*k*theta)/((sigma**2)*x1)))) + ((x1*gamma_2-((V_1*(x1**2))/(V_1*x1+V_2-(1-t)*(C/r))))/((gamma_2*k*theta)/((1-gamma_2)*(sigma**2)+k))))
```
For the inputs I have given earlier the answer for x1 should be (with 4 decimals), 0.4389 if that provides an explanation. 

I greatly appreciate the feedback this far.

Comment: You should use SymPy's (symbolic) `hyper` function rather than mpmath's (numeric) `hyp1f1`.

Comment: Yes, if you can figure out the relationship between `hyper` and `hyp1f1` it would be good to use a symbolic function.

Comment: Answer has been updated with the corrected function and gives the anticipated value for a solution.